# bash find parameters

Tags: bash, find

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                             
menu=0
dir=""
size=""
name=""
modif=""
while [ $menu -ne 6 ]
do
    echo "1. Name: $name"
    echo "2. Directory $dir"
    echo "3. Last modified: $modif"
    echo "4. Minimum size: $size"
    echo "5. Search"
    echo "6. End"
    read menu
    case "$menu" in
        "1") read name ;;
        "2") read dir ;;
        "3") read modif ;;
        "4") read size;;
        "5") if [ -z $name ]
             then
                 option1=""
             else
                 option1="-name $name"
             fi
            find "$option1";;
        "6") ;;
        *) echo "Wrong number!"
    esac
done
```

I need to make a script which will be working like find command, but I've encountered a problem. When user doesnt input for example name the find command should have name option disabled.

I came up with something like this above, but it doestn work when the variable name doesnt contain anything (user didnt input anything). I keep getting error: 
find: paths must precede expression: BASH ....

I honestly have no idea how to make it work instead of having 2^4 IF's and executing find with only those specified options that user has choosen.

Is there any way to make it easier?

edit: Now i modified it to:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                             
menu=0
dir=""
modif=""
while [ $menu -ne 6 ]
do
    echo "1. Name: $name"
    echo "2. Directory $dir"
    echo "3. Last modified: $modif"
    echo "4. Minimum size: $size"
    echo "5. Search"
    echo "6. End"
    read menu
    case "$menu" in
        "1") 
            read name 
            ;;
        "2") read dir ;;
        "3") read modif ;;
        "4") 
            read size
            ;;
        "5") 
            if [ -z $name ]
        then
            unset tablica[0]
        else    
            tablica[0]="-name $name"
        fi          
        find "${tablica[@]}"
        ;;
    "6") ;;
    *) echo "Wrong number!"
esac
done
```

But another error:

find: unknown predicate `-name example.txt'

Comment: This `if [ -z $name ]` should be `if [ -z "$name" ]`, strictly, though `test` (aka `[`) may compensate for the missing argument.

Comment: use `tablica[0]="-name"; tablica[1]="$name"; `, or much more conveniently, `tablica+=(-name "$name")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an array of parameters:

```
myarray=()
if [[ $size ]]
then
    myarray+=(-size +"$size")
fi

if [[ $name ]]
then
    myarray+=(-name "$name")
fi
...
find "$dir" "${myarray[@]}"
```

The benefit of this approach is that it also handles spaces correctly, and doesn't allow code injection.

Comment: But will this work properly if I once have name set lets say to example.txt and then without quitting the program i change it by pressing 1 to else.txt. As i see it will add a new element to array so it will now have two kinda same elements: -name example.txt and -name else.txt

Comment: You would do this in your case "5" when you actually want to run the find command, after the variables have been read in and modified as many times as the user want.